# How to fix videos not displaying on deployment using AWS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, dom

In localhost these videos work as expected using OnMouseHover and OnMouseOut, however when I deploy the site, the videos don't show up and I get an error saying : "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The element has no supported sources." The videos are uploaded to my github but I suspect that isn't the issue. Can anyone guide me as to how to fix this?

Here's my code:

```
interface ICanvasProps {
canvas: {
name: string;
src: any;
}
}

export function Canvas(props: ICanvasProps) {

const { canvas } = props

return (

        {
      canvas.map((canva) => {

              return (
        <div key={canva.name} className='card'>

         <video
                    preload={'auto'}
                    autoPlay
                    loop
                    onLoad={()=>{"I am loaded"}}
                    //@ts-ignore
                    onMouseOver = { (event) => event.target.play() }
                    //@ts-ignore
                    onMouseOut = { (event) => event.target.pause() }
        style={{ 
                            width: '100%',
                            borderRadius:"10px"
                        }}
            src={canva.src}></video>
         </div>
            )
        })
        }

    </div>
)

}
```

I tried looking for issues using event.target and suspect it could be because the browser cannot load the videos before displaying them but I am unsure how to load the videos since I'm mapping through an array of sources. `

Comment: How many video elements are you rendering, and do they all have properly set sources?

Comment: @FiddlingAway it's dynamically receiving different arrays of objects with a "name" property and a "src" property. In those list I used require("xxx") as typescript needs me to do that. In localhost it works fine so I know it's able to find the files but in my deployment I keep getting the "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The element has no supported sources"

Comment: What do you see when you inspect one of the video elements? Is the `src` attribute properly set? If it is, what do you get when you try to open that `src` link?